# How to use MoveFile function of windows.h The function is prepending the path in filename

Tags: c++, windows

```
path[ ]="folder" ;

strcat(path,fname) ;

MoveFile(fname,path) ;
```

how to use MoveFile function of windows.h The function is prepending the path in filename

Answer (score 0):

The way you are initializing `path`, it only has room to hold `"folder"`, you can't append anything more to it without overflowing memory. You need to allocate more space for it, eg:

```
char path[MAX_PATH] = {};
strcpy(path, "folder");
strcat(path, "\\");
strcat(path, fname);
```

However, using the Win32 API [`PathCombine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571.aspx) (or related) function (or a 3rd party solution like `boost::filesystem`) would be safer:

```
char path[MAX_PATH] = {};
PathCombine(path, "folder", fname);
```

Now, with that said, you are passing `fname` as the first argument to `MoveFile()`. Assuming `fname` contains just a filename and no path, `MoveFile()` will look for the file in a path that is relative to the calling process's current working directory, which is a dynamic value that can (and usually does) change during the process's lifetime. NEVER rely on relative paths, ALWAYS use absolute paths instead.

```
char src[MAX_PATH] = {};
strcpy(src, "source folder");
strcat(src, "\\");
strcat(src, fname);
// or: PathCombine(src, "source folder", fname);

char dst[MAX_PATH] = {};
strcpy(dst, "destination folder");
strcat(dst, "\\");
strcat(dst, fname);
// or: PathCombine(dst, "destination folder", fname);

MoveFile(src, dst);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply . 
I figured out what was the problem .
Actually was looping and concating the path so in each iteration the new file name was appended into path therefore the filename get changed .

But i solved it by assigning  '\0' null character at the position from where i want to concat in each iteration .